# Unity profiler Device.present

Tags: unity-game-engine, optimization, mobile, profiler

When trying to optimize my game the biggest problem seems to be the device.present. Been going through some forums and i couldnt really find any useful answers. What is usually the main problem associated with this?

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is waiting for Vsync/Vblank. Often caused by being too fast/slow.

Comment: Well i set Vsync in the QulatiySettings to Dont Sync.

Comment: Which device specifically are you targeting? As I know certain devices enforce Vsync

Comment: Now im testing on Android but in the future i would like to foucs on IOS.

Comment: By my knowledge, android enforces Vsync.

Comment: That's...a lot of PresentAndSync. Way more than is necessary.  That's weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are just many things that could cause this but the main reason is because the Thread is blocked by the graphics driver in a way to let the GPU catch up.

These are the specific reasons:

**1**.Image Effects

Check your camera. If you have Image Effects such as [*Flare Layer*](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FlareLayer.html), [Anti-aliasing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessing-Antialiasing.html) and others, disable them.

**2**.UI Effects

Check all your *Images*, *RawImages* and *Texts*. If you have an `Outline`, `Shadow` or `Position As UV1` component attached to the `Images`, `RawImages` and `Texts`, this could cause the problem. Usually when you have multiple of this attached to one 
 `Image`, `RawImage` and `Text`.

**3**.Bad Light Settings

Select your light and make sure that the *Resolution* under the *Shadow Type* is **not** set to *Very High Resolution*.

[image]

**4**.In the *Quality Setting* change the V Sync Count  to *Don't Sync*.

**5**.Check for Sprites and Images with `0` alpha then disabled them

**6**.From the *Player Settings*, disable *Auto Graphics API* then change the *Graphics API* to *OpenGLES2*.

**7**.Custom Shaders

Are you using custom shaders (non standard shaders)? Disable it temporary. An expensive or bad written shaders could cause this problem.

---

Those are the usual problems. It is very possible that yours is a different problem. I suggest you enable/disable items one by one and you will likely find the problem.

If not, then consider creating new project and scene. Save out your old game as prefabs or assets then import them one by one into the new project. Don't import them at the-same time because the problem might appear again. Import then test then import again and test until you find the problem. If the problem is no longer there then it's likely an Editor Settings problem.

Comment: Oh, also check batching. Unity Editor, game window, top right, click stats.  Usually this shows up as delay as the number of times Camera.Render > Draw is called, but its possible that the numbers are being obfuscated by the sync time. For mobile more draw calls the worse the performance; for mobile you want to keep this number under 100, ideally *under 10*.  High batching numbers -> fewer draw calls, and *all kinds of things* break batching.

Comment: That's a possible problem too.